# Create a graph from an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, graph

I am using commands in MATLAB to create graphs by specifying the connection between nodes. For instance, a tube with two branches can be represented using the following

```
Graph=graph([1 2 3 4 3 5],[2 3 4 6 5 7])
plot(Graph)
```

Can we create such graphs from images? The following image shows three branches from a tube.I want to create graphs out of images like these with three nodes in each branch, irrespective of how it appears in the image. In the image, the third branch is longer than the other two. But, I want to assign three nodes for all the branch lengths.

I would like to ask for suggestions on how a graph can be created from an image.In the end, I want to obtain the adjacency matrix and degree from the graph.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: @beaker I could get the skeleton structures for my image like the ones shown in the link that you have posted. Could you please give suggestions on how to proceed from this structure [link] (https://github.com/DeepaMahm/cytoscape/blob/master/Network.png) to a graph of nodes and edges?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246747/matlab-image-skeleton-to-adjacency-matrix#comment93419012_53246747 It all depends on what you're planning on doing with the graph.

Comment: @beaker From the graph that is created from the skeleton image, I want to find out the Laplacian matrix from the degree and adjacency matrix and solve a fluid flow problem using the Laplacian. I also read through the suggestions posted in the comment in the above link shared by you. My knowledge of image processing is limited, could you please provide a sample code that shows how this can be done?